# Python; Write output to new file in Unix format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With python, I create a file with IDs from multiple files (basenames in this code)

```
ID = basename + ' ' + str(i) + ' ' + record.id 
with open('ID.out' ,'a', newline='\n') as ID_file: 
    ID_file.write(ID)
```

My output looks like this

```
Base1 1 ID1
Base1 2 ID2
Base2 1 ID1
Base2 2 ID2
```

In my script, I want to use this file, and load it as dataframe. I use the following code

```
df = pd.read_csv('ID.out', header=None, sep=' ', names = ['base', 'number', 'ID'])
```

However, when I do this, the dataframe reads not the different columns, it puts everything in one column

```
base / Base1 1 ID1Base1 2 ID2Base2 1 ID1Base2 2 ID2
number / Base1 1 ID1Base1 2 ID2Base2 1 ID1Base2 2 ID2
ID / Base1 1 ID1Base1 2 ID2Base2 1 ID1Base2 2 ID2
```

I tried to set a newline after the records

```
ID = basename + ' ' + str(i) + ' ' + record.id + '\n'
```

And than the dataframe looks ok, but only loads the last added bases to the df

```
  base  number ID
0 Base2 1      ID1
1 Base2 1      ID2
```

How can I change my code that the ID.out file is written correctly to be loaded as dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write` puts only exactly the string you tell it to in the file. Explicitly put a newline as well;

```
    ID_file.write(ID + '\n')
```

or use `print` instead, which supplies a newline at the end of each written string (unless you explicitly tell it otherwise).